# Can, and if so how, may a non-Erudite psionic character learn a spellpower?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, powers, psionics

Spellpowers are powers that are converted into powers from spells by the *Convert Spell to Power* Erudite alternate class feature. They are powers for all intents and purposes. But they do not seem to appear on any class list of powers, even the Erudite list.

Psychic Chirurgery should be able to do the trick, but what about Expanded Knowledge or researching the power to add it to another list?

What methods can a psionic character learn a spellpower without being a StP Erudite themself?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Wasn’t me, but I could certainly see reasoning along the lines of “spell to power is horribly broken and should never be used, so asking questions about it is not useful,” and “not useful” is an explicitly-suggested reason for a downvote. I’m tempted to downvote for that same reason, myself, and certainly see it as a reason to avoid upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Once an erudite has used convert spell to power, that spell now exists as a psionic power, even if only that erudite knows it. Which, RAW, means that it’s a valid choice for Expanded Knowledge—that feat says you can learn “any power.” The subsequent clause referencing other power lists is introduced by “including,” and so it represents a non-exhaustive example subset. So it provides no limitation on selecting powers *not* on other classes’ power lists. There aren’t even any rules requiring the character who takes the feat to demonstrate that knowledge of the power’s existence—though a DM could rule that a particular spell isn’t a valid choice because no erudite has ever converted it to a power. I’d certainly rule that way, because in my games erudites certainly do not have that ability in the first place.

I’d say a DM would have to be insane to allow that, but then we’re talking about a hypothetical DM that allowed convert spell to power in the first place, so maybe that’s precisely what they are. **Nonetheless, there do not exist strong enough terms for me to stress how much I consider allowing spell to power to be a horrible mistake, and allowing access to the results via Expanded Knowledge is an even larger one.**

---

Doesn’t help with learning the power, but just because it’s frequently forgotten, [you can manifest other people’s powers](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#manifestAnUnknownPowerFromAnothersPowersKnown), which would work for manifesting a converted spell if a friendly erudite was around to work with. Again, I strongly recommend that it be impossible to find such an erudite to make friends with, because I strongly recommend that no erudite have the ability to begin with.

Comment: Is asking a question such as "how would @kryan fix the Erudite StP ability such that it retains its function, but is no longer considered broken in his opinion, " a valid question for the stack?

Comment: @nijineko It’s not, and even asking how to fix it, without the reference to me, is dubious—and not a question I would answer. I think it’s a pretty terrible idea on its face, and also one that is near impossible to balance, and since I think it’s terrible I haven’t tried to do so, and it is much too complex to offer something untested.